# Circles in a slideshow not going back to non-active

Tags: javascript

I have the following function, which changes the picture in a slider, according to a count variable. Also a circle is set to active. Now the problem is that the circles stay active even when the picture is changing. How can I make it so that they are unactive again, and only the one that belongs to the picture is active?

```
function picChange(counter) {

 if (counter == 0) {
        slide.src = "slike/slide_1.png";
        circle1.src = "slike/active.png";
 }

 else if (counter == 1) {
        slide.src = "slike/prva.jpg";
        circle2.src = "slike/active.png";
 }

  else if (counter == 2) {
        slide.src = "slike/slide_1.png";
        circle3.src = "slike/active.png";
 }

   else {
        slide.src = "slike/druga.jpg";
        circle4.src = "slike/active.png";
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
circle1.src = "slike/unactive.png";
circle2.src = "slike/unactive.png";
circle3.src = "slike/unactive.png";
circle4.src = "slike/unactive.png";
```

to the beginning of your method. This will set all circles to unactive first, and then setting the one you want to active.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use closures to save a reference to the active circle.

```
var picChange = (function () {
    var activeCircle = null;

    return function (counter) {
        activeCircle && activeCircle.src = "slike/inactive.png"; // or ''?

        if (counter == 0) {
            slide.src = "slike/slide_1.png";
            activeCircle = circle1;
        } 

        else if (counter == 1) {
            slide.src = "slike/prva.jpg";
            activeCircle = circle2;
        } 

        else if (counter == 2) {
            slide.src = "slike/slide_1.png";
            activeCircle = circle3;
        }

        else {
            slide.src = "slike/druga.jpg";
            activeCircle = circle4;
        }

        activeCircle.src = "slike/active.png";
    };
})();
```

Comment: Better with 
 activeCircle && activeCircle.src = "slike/inactive.png";

Comment: No problem, we are here to help   ;)